# After certain disk operations such as enumerating disks, HDD light may start flashing every second and storage subsystem hangs after sleep and resume

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, freeze, sleep, intel-rst

I'm dealing with some weird problem that's been making my computer crash.

- On occasion (but not always), when I perform certain disk operations (something to do with enumerating disks, as this happens when I open Disk Management), the application hangs and my laptop's disk busy light starts flashing every second.
- The system functions normally during this period otherwise, but as soon as I put the system to sleep and wake it up, **the storage subsystem hangs and all disks stop responding.** This ultimately leads to a BSOD, often 0x7A `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR`. Oddly enough, **the system is able to write the crash dump**, strongly suggesting this is an Intel Rapid Storage Technology glitch.
- The issue seems to be associated with my Thermaltake BlacX hard drive dock, but can occur even when the dock is never plugged into my computer.
- The Intel RST driver is currently at version 13.2.4.1000. The disks themselves seem to be working normally as all SMART tests pass. Chipset is Intel HM87 The disks attached to the system are as follows:

  - SATA 0: WD Black 750 GB
  - SATA 1: Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512 GB
  - SATA 2: *eSATA*
  - SATA 3: CD/DVD drive
  - SATA 4: *mSATA:* *Unused*
  - SATA 5: *mSATA:* Plextor M5M 64 GB

Comment: Have you run disk diagnostics on the drives?

Comment: All SMART tests pass, and there are no bad sectors. Samsung Magician reports no problems with my SSD.

Comment: Manufacturer disk diagnostics - [[Western Digital](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=612&sid=3), [Samsung SSD Tools](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html)]

Comment: I'm really tempted to drop to the stock Microsoft StorAHCI driver, but I'm not really sure if this is a great idea or if the problem will persist after removing the IRST driver.

Comment: Until you try, you'll never know. I usually installed the IRST drivers *after* Windows gets installed, but that's just me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver version 13.2.4.1000 contains a bug where the driver appears to be attempting to access a device that does not exist.

- Upon removing the Intel RST driver and reverting to the stock StorAHCI driver, the problem could no longer be reproduced. The issue did not reappear upon installing version 12.9.0.1001 of Intel RST.
- As mentioned in the question, the problem would manifest itself as disk enumeration operations (such as by Disk Management) hanging or taking a very long time to complete especially when the eSATA hard drive dock was connected, then later disconnected. The HDD access LED would then start flashing and the entire storage subsystem would hang upon resuming from sleep.
- During said enumeration operations, Intel RST may generate the following pop-up from the notification area, even though no new SATA disk is connected. This indicates that the driver is somehow trying to communicate with a "phantom device":

  > #### Intel® Rapid Storage Technology
  >
  > SATA disk on Controller 0, Port Unknown: Detected.
- In short, **don't update the Intel RST driver to 13.2.4.1000!**